# Shortcut functions of Libre Calc

Tags: shortcut-keys, libreoffice

I am new to Ubuntu as well as Libre Office. I find it bit difficult to use Libre Calc without shortcut keys. Since I am used to shortcut keys in MS Excel, I tend to be very fast, but in Libre Calc I am way too slow.

Just like MS office, I tried with <kbd>alt</kbd> key to display shortcuts. but it doesn't work.

So can anyone just help me with the shortcut keys in Libre Ccalc for formatting cells like changing fonts, adjusting row height, column width, font size, applying borders, applying filters, v lookup, h lookup, and other data formatting?

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If the below answers your question, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of the answer, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formatting cells --- `F11`

Increase height of current row  --- `Alt` + `↓`

Decrease height of current row  --- `Alt` + `↑`

Increase width of current row  --- `Alt` + `→`

Decrease width of current row  --- `Alt` + `←`

These are few shortcuts I use.

For more check [Shortcut Keys for Spreadsheets](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Shortcut_Keys_for_Spreadsheets)